# How to add infowindow on googlemap heatmap overlay containing thousands of coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, events, infowindow, heatmap

I need to create a visualization of pollution in Google maps and I used Heatmap overlay for the rendering of results. However, I need to add a click event on Heatmap. I already read on some questions that Heatmap Overlay cannot handle click events so they suggested to use transparent rectangles to handle events. But with the sheer amount of data that I need to render (over 500,000 coordinates), google maps just crash when I use rectangles instead of heatmaps.. How can I exactly handle click events on heatmaps without using rectangles?

Comment: What do you like to display in the infowindow?

Comment: I like to display the coordinates of the clicked heatmap.. how can I do that?